# How to check the unit test coverage for the new code on local

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

My company is going to force a new code unit testing coverage to allow the code merged. We have this number available on SonarQube after we commit and push to the remote branch. I was wondering if there is any tool/way for me to have a clue about this "new code" unit test coverage before I commit and push. Otherwise, I might end up with too many commits. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question, why a lot of commits is bad? We do a lot of commits, even with stupid commit messages `fix` etc. When all is finally done, we squash them into logical packages and give a nice detailed commit messages. It makes the development easier, the git history is clean and we don't need to think how to document the code, which could be declined by a reviewer :)

Comment: I see. Thanks, @agabrys. That's what the company is doing. Just want to see if anyway we can save this kind of back and forth commit only for meeting the coverage.